# How to use and set arrays in Redshift JDBC PreparedStatement with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jdbc, prepared-statement, amazon-redshift

I have a Kotlin code which use a Redshift JDBC PreparedStatement but the parameters seems not correctly inserted into the statement. When I insert via `.replace("?", "something")` it works.

This code isn't working (I'm using the prepared statement and set the array):

```
val existingContacts =
    redshiftClient.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT contact_id, email FROM some.table WHERE email IN (?)"
    )
        .use { ps ->
            ps.setArray(1, redshiftClient.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", dataToInsert.mapNotNull { it["email"] }.toTypedArray()))
            ps.executeQuery().use { rs ->
                mutableListOf<Pair<String, Map<String, String?>>>().apply {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        add(rs.getString("contact_id") to dataToInsert.first { d -> d["email"] == rs.getString("email") })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This code is working (I'm inserting by myself the array):

```
val existingContacts =
    redshiftClient.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT contact_id, email FROM some.table WHERE email IN (?)"
            .replace(
                "?",
                dataToInsert.mapNotNull { it["email"] }.joinToString(
                    separator = "','",
                    prefix = "'",
                    postfix = "'"
                )
            )
    )
        .use { ps ->
            ps.executeQuery().use { rs ->
                mutableListOf<Pair<String, Map<String, String?>>>().apply {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        add(rs.getString("contact_id") to dataToInsert.first { d -> d["email"] == rs.getString("email") })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If I use another SQL query like `SELECT contact_id, email FROM some.table WHERE email IN ?` (without the parenthesis around the `?`) I got an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "$1" 
Position: 63;
```

Do you see where the error is located ?

By any chances, do you know how I can print the PreparedStatement with the Redshift JDBC ? `println(ps.toString())` isn't working, is it implemented ?

Thanks,